# How to implement a re-sizable border + making it invisible using MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I was wondering, how do I create a re-sizable border in MFC without showing the border itself?

```
IDD_GADGETTRANSLUCENTDIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 201
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
```

The "WS_THICKFRAME" style provides the functionality of resizing, but I don't want the border to be visible. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't know anything about MFC - but in plain C++ you can process the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx) message yourself, and return the appropriate value to signal that a resizeable border or corner has been hit by the cursor.

Comment: ok, i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a MCF application that has the borders (and frame) as optional.  When in the mode of no border, I still wanted it resizable and movable, so essentially in `OnMouseMove` if I was within a few pixels of the edge of the window, I set the appropriate cursor (e.g. `IDC_SIZENESW` for the top right corner) then if `nFlags & MK_LBUTTON` did a `SendMessage` using `WM_SYSCOMMAND` and the appropriate size command (e.g. `SC_SIZE + WMSZ_TOPRIGHT`) and let the `CWnd::OnSysCommand` default handler process it.  Also, same trick works with `SC_MOVE`...

Answer (score 2):

Or handle WM_NCPAINT and draw the borders (and caption) yourself...

Comment: In hindsight, I think that melak47's suggestion is the better one because redrawing the titlebar just to change the border is way over the top.

If you want help with that, I'm happy to help out.